# Getting empty item and same item when fetching data react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating app to get pokemons, first I save them in a list and after that show them, but I am getting empty card and after that the same pokemon is showing even if I am searching for another one.
Also I am getting distortion view when I use my component `<Card>`.

```
 import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import "./App.css";
    import { v4 } from "uuid";

import Button from "./Components/Button";
import Input from "./Components/Input";
import Label from "./Components/Label";
import Card from "./Components/Card";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  // const [textFromInput, setTextFromInput] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [nameFromButtonClick, setNameFromButtonClick] = useState("");
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState({
    name: "",
    picture: "",
    id: 0,
    type1: "",
    type2: "",
  });
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => setName(event.target.value);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setNameFromButtonClick(name);
    setList([...list, pokemon]);
  };
  // const handleClick = () => setList([...list, pokemon]);


  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}/`)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        //  setPokemon(res.data);
        console.log("res.data=>", res.data);
        setPokemon({
          name: res.data.name,
          picture: res.data.sprites.front_default,
          id: res.data.id,
          type1: res.data.types[0].type.name,
          type2: res.data.types[1].type.name,
        });
        
        
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [nameFromButtonClick]);

  return (
<div className="App">
      <div>
        <h1>Pokémon Effect</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="centered">
            <div className="container">
                    {list.map((entry) => (
                     <Card key ={v4()} 
                    name={entry.name} 
                    picture={entry.picture} 
                    id={entry.id} 
                    type1={entry.type1}
                    type1={entry.type2}
                    />
                  ))}
           
            </div>
            <div className="dashboard">
            <Input className="input" value={name} onChange={handleChange} />
            <Button
              className="getPokemon"
              text="GetPokemon"
              onClick={handleClick}
            />
            <Label text={name} />
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is my component Card, I don't know how to make it look like when I ma writing directly in app.js

```
export default function Card(props){
const{name, picture,id,type1,type2}=props
    return(
        <div className="card">
            <div><img src={picture} alt={name} /></div>
            <p>n:{id}</p>
            <div> name={name}</div>
            <div className="pokeType">
                <div className="classType">type={type1}</div>
                <div className="classType">type={type2}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: Can you remove the use of v4() in the key and replace it with the index of the map, or better the id of your data ? Because since it change on every render it can give you unconsistent result

https://medium.com/blackrock-engineering/5-common-mistakes-with-keys-in-react-b86e82020052

Comment: Also be carefull when you do 

 setNameFromButtonClick(name); // ==> trigger an async request and update the current pkmn

Then you do that : 

setList([...list, pokemon]); 

// You want to read the pokemon directly, it may not be ready

Comment: I do what you suggest and still not working properly.